# Want to call two ajax function on a single form in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I have the following form in view and it is submitting through an ajax call that search for some thing from the site:

```
        <div id="main_form">
        <?php $attributes = array('name' => 'analyze', 'id' => 'analyze', 'method' => 'POST'); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('user/add_domain', $attributes); ?>
           <div>
              <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Website URL to review" id="domain" name="domain" value="" />
              <span class="input_bg">client-domain.com</span>
              <input id="submit_btn" type="submit"  class="submit" value="Review Site" />
            </div>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
```

And i have the following AJAX code that is used to submit it.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#analyze").submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: $("#analyze").serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
                        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
                        $("#overlayimage").css("display", "block");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        location = "<?php echo $root ?>site/" + data;
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

Now i want another AJAX function call on submitting of the above form. that will be a controller function and will add the records to database. so i need to trigger two AJAX functions on a single form. 1st one will search from site and second will be a controller/method that add the records to database

```
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "controller/method",}
```

Comment: what happens if you add the second ajax call in the success handler of the first one?

Comment: its just call the first AJAX function and search from the site, but not added the records to database,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the second ajax call after the first ajax but before the return.

```
$("#analyze").submit(function () {
    formData = new FormData($("#analyze")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        processData: false, 
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
            overlay.appendTo(document.body);
            $("#overlayimage").css("display", "block");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            location = "<?php echo $root ?>site/" + data;
        }
    });
            // JUST PUT YOUR SECOND AJAX CALL HERE BEFORE THE RETURN
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getBaseUrl() + "user/add_domain",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            // do what ever you want after the controller's method finish
        }
    });
    //THE RETURN TO CANCEL THE ACTION FOR THAT FORM AND STOP EVERY THING.
    return false;
});

function getBaseUrl() {
    var l = window.location;
    var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host+ "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1];
    return base_url;
}
```

Comment: By the way what will be my form action in this case? right now i have empty action="". and the above solution not worked for me :(

Comment: let's say your  request is going to the action you put in your form. so you need to make it empty in form action and the second request will be like this url: 'user/add_domain',

Comment: do you a remote computer access? @Alaa so u can check it on my PC tat is the exact issue is

Comment: do you have teamviewer ? that will be easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98436/discussion-between-shoaib-fareed-and-alaa-m-jaddou).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's AJAX calls support chaining of actions because they implement *promises*. To make an action trigger once some other action has finished, you may make use of the methods that a promise supports, namely `done()`, `then()`, `fail()`, etc. See [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

So in your case, what you wanted to achieve could be done using the promise returned by `$.ajax()`:

```
 $("#analyze").submit(function () {
            var promise = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: $("#analyze").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
                    $("#overlayimage").css("display", "block");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    location = "<?php echo $root ?>site/" + data;
                }
            });

            promise.done(function(){
                // perform the action after previous has finished
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "controller/method"
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by @Alex Andre, you can simply add your second AJAX call in the success handler of the first one. This could be a preferred approach if you want to make sure your ajax call has was *successful*, and upon its success, you may proceed:

```
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: $("#analyze").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
                    $("#overlayimage").css("display", "block");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    location = "<?php echo $root ?>site/" + data;
                    //second ajax call here
                }
            });
```

Comment: this will make the requests continously, like the first one when it finish the second one run, he need two ajax requests at a time